# error: appcompat_v7 project in values-large-v14

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-library

Everything was going totally fine in my eclipse and then I deleted all the projects in my eclipse even appcompat_v7 and I removed them from my workspace also. Now there is just one folder in my eclipse named .metadata.

When I create a new android aplication project, an appcompat_v7 project also gets created in my eclipse. But there are errors in both my project and in appcompat_v7 project.

The error in appcompat project is in the res/values-large-v14/themes_base.xml directory and the error itself is:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
```

I would be VERY happy if someone can help me. I was searching for this problem for days. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you are just creating a new project, switch to Android Studio, Eclipse  Android ADT plugin is no longer supported by Google.

Comment: I have created a simple program and now I want to do the second version of it that's why I cant change it now @JaredBurrows

Comment: It takes seconds to copy and paste into Android Studio. I am just making a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) you mean i dont have to change anything? and there are no difference between them? @JaredBurrows

Comment: I would read this first: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html; however, I would suggest making a new project in Android Studio, with the same package names and then copy and paste your code into the project. This makes a new, nice and clean project for you.

Comment: I can help you walk through. Let me know.